# Cant pass parameter from store vuex in api call using router

Tags: vue.js

I try to fetch data with axios get with parameter that come from vuex store.
Problem is i get parameter undefined altought is in the store

```
    data() {
    return {
      payments: [],
      destinations: [],
    };
  },
    computed: {
    codcli() {
      return this.$store.getters.codcli;
    },
    total() {
      return this.$store.getters.orderTotal;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setData(payments, destinations) {
      this.payments = payments;
      this.destinations = destinations;
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    axios
      .all([
        axios.get(`/api/payments/${this.codcli}/${this.total}`),
        axios.get(`/api/getcustomerdestinations/${this.codcli}`)
      ])
      .then(
        axios.spread((payments, destinations) => {
          next(vm => vm.setData(payments.data, destinations.data));
          console.log(payments.data, destinations.data);
        })
        .catch(error=> console.log(error))
      );
  }
```

what's going on here? what i mess? cant understand because the getters of vuex works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The component's instance has not been created yet when
>   `beforeRouteEnter` is executed and that is why you don't have access to
>   `this`.

Taken from the official [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard):

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  // called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.
  // does NOT have access to `this` component instance,
  // because it has not been created yet when this guard is called!
},
```

One possible solution to this is by importing the main `store` file in this component and using it directly for accessing the getters instead instead of using the `computed` properties.

Assuming that this component and the store file exists in the same root folder level:

```
import store from "./store";
```

And access the getters like this:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  const codcli = store.getters.codcli;
  const total = store.getters.orderTotal;
  axios
    .all([
      axios.get(`/api/payments/${codcli}/${total}`),
      axios.get(`/api/getcustomerdestinations/${codcli}`)
    ])
    .then(
      axios.spread((payments, destinations) => {
        next(vm => vm.setData(payments.data, destinations.data));
        console.log(payments.data, destinations.data);
      })
      .catch(error=> console.log(error))
    );
},
```

Comment: It all depends on what kind of user experience you're trying to achieve. Fetching the data before or after navigation to a specific route are both valid. If you decide to stick to fetching the data before navigation to that route, then you should display some kind of progress/loading indicator to the user.

Comment: tks ... you are nice and smart... marry me! :)

Comment: Hahaha, that would be a really interesting story, meeting in SO.

Comment: if you come in italy ... :) bye

Comment: Ciao, a presto.:)